# How do I access an SQL image column using an External Content Type list?

Tags: external-content-type, business-data-catalog, image

I have a External Content Type (list) which pulls the data from an SQL Server. The image field in SQL can be stored in binary format or just the image path is stored (currently I am storing the path as `/_layouts/images/1.jpg`).

I get the data available in my External Content Type list, but the images from SQL are not available in the external content type. I want to see the images from SQL or at least pull the image path from SQL and show it in the External Content Type .

Alternatively, is there a solution where I can get the data as image path from sql and show in the External Content type list? Any alternative solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about trying to save the path of the image in your table and when you access it from SharePoint you use the image column and it looks for the path in the table so display it, as if the path is images library.

I haven't tried it but see and tell us how is it.